# Does all marketo users have access to latest (2_9) SOAP endpoint?

Tags: marketo

Does all the Marketo users have access to latest SOAP endpoint i.e. v2_9 Or some of the users can be restricted to older endpoints? 
Can all users connect to v2_9 endpoint?

Also, When we are switching between the End_points, can we just add the  to the base URI? i.e. Will the URI format will always remain the same for all the endpoints?
https:///soap/mktows/

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Marketo subscription with API access has access to all published versions of the SOAP API at this time.

Comment: Thanks Kelkington, I have edited question to seek more information about the format of Marketo SOAP URI."Will the URI format will always remain the same for all the endpoints?"

Comment: Always is a long time, but there are no plans or desire to change this pattern now as far as I know.